# redirect from inside a frame to external page and "clear the frame"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I have an app that loads a page inside an iframe. Everything works well.but i am at a stage when i need to redirect to another site and its still loading this 'external site inside my frame'...this isn't what i want. How do i get rid of the frame as i no longer have need for it.

here's my controller action where i'm redirecting:

```
      public ActionResult Finish()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
        {

            string url = string.Format("{0}?code={1}",Url,code);

            return Redirect(url);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I added the iframe in my view like this:

```
 <div>    
 <iframe id="paymentFrame" width="600px" height="670px" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src='@Url.Action("myForm")'></iframe>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

 function sendISWPostData() {

     $("#paymentFrame").load(function () {

         var doc = this.contentDocument;
         var form = doc.getElementById('form1');
         var actionUrl = '@ViewBag.WebPayUrl';
         form.action = actionUrl;

         $(this).contents().find(':input[name=cust_name]').val('@ViewBag.CustName');
         $(this).contents().find(':input[name=cust_id]').val('@ViewBag.CustNumber');

         form.submit();

         //return true;


     });   //end load
 }  // end send

 $(document).ready(function () {
 sendISWPostData();
 //return true;
});
```

Comment: Are both parent and iframe documents on the same domain?

Comment: yes...but i want to redirect to another page on another domain

Comment: Okay, you can have anything for redirecting page but to be able to access parent document within iframe using javascript both should be in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript, within the iframe page, following line will redirect/replace the parent window:

```
self.parent.location.replace('www.google.com');
```